# Spring Data JPAの複数IDのアクセス方法について質問

Tags: java, spring, jpa

SpringBootを使ってWEBシステム開発を行っています。
JPAのfindById(ID id)で汎用的にデータを取得する方法は分かるのですが
Entityに複数の@IDを設定して、複数のIDでデータ取得したいと考えています。
今一つ実装方法がわかりません。サンプルも少なくて、、、
この場合、findAllById(Iterable ids)使うのでしょうか？

補足
findBy△△And〇〇()メソッド以外の方法を探しています。

Comment: 大変失礼いたしました。
そもそも「Entityに複数の@Idを設定」することはできない問ことを理解しました。別な方法を考えます。
ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

アノテーション [`@IdClass`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/IdClass.html) で複合主キーを表現できます

```java
@Entity
@IdClass(FullName.class)
public class Person {

    @Id
    private String sei;
    @Id
    private String mei;

    private LocalDate birthday;

    // getters and setters
}
```

```java
public class FullName implements Serializable {
    /** 姓 */
    private String sei;
    /** 名 */
    private String mei;
}
```

が、このとき、 Spring Data JPA のリポジトリインタフェースを用いる場合、単項主キーの場合と同じく、

```java
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, FullName> {
}
```

というような定義になります。
従って、主キーで検索するメソッドも変わらず主キーの型(`FullName`)を引数に採る`findById` メソッドで行うことになります。

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyController {

    private final PersonRepository personRepository;

    @GetMapping
    public Optional<Person> index() {
        return personRepository.findById(new FullName("新渡戸", "稲造"));
    }
}
```

([サンプル実装](https://github.com/yukihane/stackoverflow-qa/tree/master/jaso72892))